# How do I get a String from resources in AndroidTestCase?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-testing

In an Activity I can get a String by just calling:

```
String myString = getString(R.string.my_string_id);
```

How do I do the same thing in an [`AndroidTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply by calling:

```
String myString = getContext().getString(R.string.my_string_id);
```

All you need to do is to get the context, which is always available in an `AndroidTestCase`, and call it on that.